# How to set default value of a select dynamically from database using smarty?

Tags: php, html, smarty

I have a `select` like this:

```
<select class="fruitsSelect" name="fruits">
   <option value="Apples">Apples</option>
   <option value="Bananas">Bananas</option>
   <option value="Oranges">Oranges</option>
</select>
```

And I know that you can set a default value if you use `selected` attribute.

```
<select class="fruitsSelect" name="fruits">
      <option value="Apples">Apples</option>
      <option value="Bananas" selected>Bananas</option>
      <option value="Oranges">Oranges</option>
</select>
```

But what I am trying to do is that, from a value that I retrieve from my database (I send it to `HTML` via `PHP`) the option that I retrieve from my database would be the `selected` option (the default option).

I have the value on my HTML but I do not know how to make it be the selected option because it can change. I am using `Smarty` and trying to make some ifs statements but I cannot get it out.

How can I compare the value that I retrieve from my database with the value of the `select` and make it to be the selected option?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @gibberish As I put above, I have the value on my HTML. I have `Bananas` value on my HTML (I can show it on any input or whatever). I send to the HTML via PHP using Smarty. And no, I am not using AJAX.

Comment: @gibberish Right now, as I am using Smarty, I have a variable `$fruit` that contains the value `Bananas`.

Comment: ternary operator against an `if row equals` maybe? if that's what the question is about. Sidenote: I know nothing about Smarty, so I can't be of any help there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set default value for HTML select control in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9710475/set-default-value-for-html-select-control-in-php)

Comment: Are you creating a dynamic dropdown using html options (or have you considered doing so?) http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.html.options.tpl

Comment: @Fred-ii- The question is about that I have one value that I have retrieved from my question which value is `Bananas` and I would like to select the option with the same value in the select. As it can change, it will not be the same value always so it is why I need some kind of if statement or something to do that. I know what ternary operators are but I do not know how to focus it in the good way. If you can give me some advice (not the code) it would be great.

Comment: @scrappedcola No. I have the same dropdown always. I just want to have the default option selected depending of the value that I get from my database.

Comment: A downvote without an explanation do not help to anyone. **To the downvoter:** If you can explain why it is, I will appreciate it very much. I can add something if you think that it is forgotten.

Comment: and this http://stackoverflow.com/a/9710493/ doesn't work for you? `echo ($key == $default) ? "<option selected=\"selected\" value=\"$key\">$val</option>...` - If not, then sorry... I am not grasping the question.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I think it should be more simpler than that. I have the same dropdown all the time. The unique thing that should change is the selected option by default which should be the value that I retrieve from my database.

Comment: First, it isn't the same `dropdown` each time. This is because the 'selected' entry is on a different option element. So each `dropdown` is different. So, there must be some logic that decides to output `selected` when the `select option` html  is generated. Now, you don't show us the code that generates the select html.  That code you need to change by checking the `selectedOptionValue` against the 'currentOptionVlaue'?

Answer (score 2):

Since you specifically asked about Smarty templating, this is actually pretty easy. Use the `html_options` template from [their example](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.html.options.tpl) file and pass an identifier to the selected attribute.

Contents of `index.tpl`:

```
{html_options name=fruits options=$myOptions selected=$mySelect}
```

The only real messy part is getting the array populated from the database. Since you didn't specify that platform, I used MySQL.

First I set up a simple database table to model your example with a boolean column for selected state. This can be constrained or set however you like, but **note** for this example if multiple are set to true, then it will use the last one selected. And I used ID's as a bonus because it will probably be more useful for a non-trivial scenario. If you still want to use the same value as the option text, then just find and replace `$row['id']` with `$row['fruit']`

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS fruits;

CREATE TABLE fruits (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  fruit VARCHAR(30),
  selected BOOLEAN
);

INSERT INTO fruits (fruit,selected)
VALUES
  ('Apples',FALSE),
  ('Bananas',TRUE),
  ('Oranges',FALSE);
```

Now use php to retrieve the data, create the smarty object, set values, and finally display.

```
<?php
require_once(__DIR__.'/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/Smarty.class.php');

$database_server = "localhost";
$database_username = "username";
$database_password = "p@55W0rd";
$database_name = "example_database";

// connect to database
$mysqli = new mysqli($database_server, $database_username, $database_password, $database_name);
if ($mysqli->connect_error)
  trigger_error('Connect Error: '.$mysqli->connect_error, E_USER_ERROR);

// get records
$sql = "SELECT id, fruit, selected FROM fruits";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

  // set array index of fruit as id
  $fruits[$row['id']] = $row['fruit'];

  // get id of selected fruit
  if ($row['selected'] == true)
    $selected = $row['id'];

}


// create object
$smarty = new Smarty;

$smarty->assign('myOptions', $fruits);
$smarty->assign('mySelect', $selected);

// display it
$smarty->display('index.tpl');
```

And this results in the following output:

```html
<select name="fruits">
<option value="1">Apples</option>
<option value="2" selected="selected">Bananas</option>
<option value="3">Oranges</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the Select is hard coded you could use:

```
<select class="fruitsSelect" name="fruits">
   <option value="Apples" <?php if ($fruit == "Apples") {echo "Selected" }?> >Apples</option>
   <option value="Bananas" <?php if ($fruit == "Bananas") {echo "Selected" }?> >Bananas</option>
   <option value="Oranges" <?php if ($fruit == "Oranges") {echo "Selected" }?>>Oranges</option>
</select>
```

Note: My Php is a little rusty so forgive any syntax or stupid errors.

If the Select list is Dynamically generated, I suggest looking at what Fred-ii- suggested in comments.

Comment: `<?` doesn't work everywhere out of the box, there's a setting to enable that syntax in php.ini. Use `<?php` for better portability

Comment: @JeffPuckettII thanks for the tip. It has been 10 or more years since I've used PHP in anger.